# Stripe crashes when trying to add wrong card

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments, onactivityresult, onerror

I am having an issue with Stripe API on Android. I'm trying to add a card, and so far if you make a successful card everything works fine. If you add a card (that is meant to fail) it results in a full application crash.

I have followed stripe instructions on how to do it. But I'm not able, to catch the once it happens.

```
private fun createCardContent() {
        try{
            creditcardViewModel.requestStatusLiveData.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)
            val cardMy = com.stripe.android.model.Card.create(
                cardModel.cardNumber,
                cardModel.expMonth,
                cardModel.expYear,
                cardModel.cCV
            )
            if(cardMy.validateCard()){
                val owner = cardModel.cardOwner
                val billingDetails = PaymentMethod.BillingDetails(null, null, owner, null) 
                creditcardViewModel.stripeSetupIntent.value?.let {
                    val paymentMethodParams = PaymentMethodCreateParams.create(cardMy.toPaymentMethodParamsCard(),billingDetails,null)
                    val confirmParams = ConfirmSetupIntentParams.create(paymentMethodParams, it.client_secret)
                    try {
                     stripe.confirmSetupIntent(this, confirmParams)
                     // it gets till here, and then crashes
                    }catch(api: APIException){
                        showDialogError(getString(R.string.card_error_general))
                    }
                }
            }else{
                creditcardViewModel.requestStatusLiveData.postValue(NetworkState.SUCCESSFUL)
                showDialogError(getString(R.string.card_error_general))
            }
        }catch(e:IOException){
            showDialogError(getString(R.string.card_error_general))
        }
    }
```

I should be getting `onError` catch (in this function, but nothing)

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        stripe.onSetupResult(requestCode, data, object : ApiResultCallback<SetupIntentResult> {
            override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                showDialogError(getString(R.string.card_error_general))
                creditcardViewModel.requestStatusLiveData.postValue(NetworkState.FAILED)
            }
            override fun onSuccess(result: SetupIntentResult) {
                val setupIntent = result.intent
                val status = setupIntent.status
                if (status == StripeIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                    creditcardViewModel.requestStatusLiveData.postValue(NetworkState.SUCCESSFUL)
                    notificationViewModel.insertNotification(
                        NotificationModel(
                            GlobalConstants.NotificationCases.CARD_ADDED,
                            Date()
                        )
                    )
                    val accountFragment = parentFragment as AccountFragment
                    accountFragment.returnChildFragment()
                } else if (status == StripeIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                    showDialogError(getString(R.string.card_error_general))
                    creditcardViewModel.requestStatusLiveData.postValue(NetworkState.FAILED)
                    logd("StripeIntent", "setup-failed")
                }
            }
})
```

This is the error i'm getting when inserting stripe given test version
`4000 0000 0000 9995`

```
2020-03-12 13:09:13.096 11288-11406/com.example.testableE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-6
Process: com.example.testableE, PID: 11288
java.lang.RuntimeException: Request-id: req_Qdd21qBCr0ds33199v
com.stripe.android.exception.APIException: Your card has insufficient funds.
    at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1779)
    at com.stripe.android.PaymentController$Result.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:24)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1683)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1589)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:875)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:915)
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:9973)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:3730)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1671)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:796)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:933)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1206)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1194)
    at com.stripe.android.view.AuthActivityStarter$Host.startActivityForResult$stripe_release(AuthActivityStarter.kt:30)
    at com.stripe.android.PaymentRelayStarter$Companion$create$1.start(PaymentRelayStarter.kt:28)
    at com.stripe.android.PaymentRelayStarter$Companion$create$1.start(PaymentRelayStarter.kt:21)
    at com.stripe.android.StripePaymentController$Companion.handleError(StripePaymentController.kt:899)
    at com.stripe.android.StripePaymentController$Companion.access$handleError(StripePaymentController.kt:838)
    at com.stripe.android.StripePaymentController$ConfirmStripeIntentCallback.onError(StripePaymentController.kt:542)
    at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation.dispatchResult(ApiOperation.kt:40)
    at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation.access$dispatchResult(ApiOperation.kt:13)
    at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation$execute$1$1.invokeSuspend(ApiOperation.kt:32)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6746)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: That is a strange behavior. Have you tried putting the entire `onActivityResult` code in try-catch and check for exception behavior? As per logcat, the exception starts within the Strip SDK I suppose. But there should be a mechanism to prevent that exception.

Comment: @AtishAgrawal just tried. Same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed with stripe new version (it worked with newest `14.1.1`)
If anyone has issue with graddle, and compiling. i also updated all of the dependencies on newest versions. 
I think it might be

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2
```

That was not allowing me to compile stripe new version.
Switching to new com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3 (possibly) fixed the issue.